# Deploy to lambda edge function from aws cli

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

I am in the process of automating our deploy for a Lambda Edge function using Octopus Deploy

I have added a step to deploy the latest js code to the function, and clear the cloudfront cache, which work great. The issue I have is I need to use an aws cli command to deploy my function to the edge. However I'm not sure how to do this. If I was doing this in the console, I would use this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1mL5.png

I have looked at the AWS Lambda documentation but it doesn't seem clear on how to deploy an Edge function.

Can anyone advise please?

Answer (score 1):

The section `Deploy to Lambda@Edge` inside the AWS Lambda console calls the CloudFront API Update Distribution with the LambdaFunctionAssociations parameter.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/update-distribution.html